# Set Azure virtual machine resource group in powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, virtual-machine

I am trying to provision a VM using PowerShell and am experiencing problems. My script is as follows...

```
$image = "a699494373c04fc0bc8f2bb1389d6106__Windows-Server-2012-R2-201504.01-en.us-127GB.vhd" 
$machineName = "XYZ-Test"
$un = "VMAdmin"
$pwd = "P4ssw0rd#"
$vmStorageAccount = "https://XYZstorage.blob.core.windows.net/vhds"
$resourceGroupName = "XYZ-Resource-Group"

$vm1 = New-AzureVMConfig -Name $machineName -InstanceSize Small -ImageName $image
$vm1 | Set-AzureSubnet "QASubnet"
$vm1 | Add-AzureProvisioningConfig -Windows -AdminUserName $un -Password $pwd 
$vm1 | Add-AzureEndpoint -Name "WinRM" -Protocol "tcp" -PublicPort 5985 -LocalPort 5985
$vm1 | New-AzureVM -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -ServiceName "XYZ-Test" -Location "West Europe" -VNetName 'Group XYZ-Resource-Group XYZ-Network'
```

The problem is when I run this command in PowerShell I get the following error...

`New-AzureVM : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'ResourceGroupName'.`

I have checked the documentation at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn495159.aspx and it clearly says that -ResourceGroupName is a parameter.

The documentation is for 0.8.10 of the Microsoft Azure PowerShell module, I am using 0.9.1. Maybe the parameter was depreciated. Is there another way of doing it? Or can the VM be moved to another resource group once it has been provisioned?

Comment: I don't see the `-ResourceGroupName` parameter in the documentation link you provided. The link is actually for New-AzureVMConfig, but the New-AzureVM documentation doesn't include it either. Have you tried adding the VM to the resource group after the creation? Take a look at http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/powershell-azure-resource-manager/

Answer (score 0):

You should run this script in Azure Resource Manager mode (Switch-AzureMode -Name AzureResourceManager)

https://binary-stuff.com/post/using-azure-resource-manager

It looks like Microsoft understood a problem.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/428